# Which docker versions are supported on kubernetes 1.18 and 1.19?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, version

I found the following description about `supported docker versions` in kubernetes v1.18 and 1.19 documents.

[Container runtimes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/)

```
The Kubernetes release notes list which versions of Docker are compatible with that version of Kubernetes.
```

But I cannot find `supported docker versions` in the Relase Notes.
[v1.18 Release Notes](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/)
[v1.19 Release Notes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/)

Also, I check the other k8s documents.
v1.15 and v1.16 document describe `supported docker versions`.
The documents specifically list them.
[v1.15 Release Notes](https://v1-15.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/)
[v1.16 Release Notes](https://v1-16.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/)

```
The list of validated docker versions remains unchanged.
The current list is 1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09, 18.06, 18.09. (#72823, #72831)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/releases/1.19-notes/ the Docker 19.03.11 for Kubernetes 1.18+ will be supported.

[Docker 19.03.11 for Kubernetes 1.18+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fokBI.png)

Comment: Thank you for your information! I confirm Docker 19.03.11 can be used for Kubernetes 1.18+.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is no information about docker version for 1.18 and 1.19 kubernetes version.

You can suggest documentation upgrade using this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/new?title=Improvement%20for%20k8s.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) for kubernetes team to include theses information.

Comment: Thank you for your investigation and giving the link. I am going to ask kubernetes team to upgrade the document about validated docker version on kubernetes v1.18 and 1.19.

Answer (score 0):

The change logs for all of the Kubernetes versions, and information on supported versions of Docker, are also specified on the following webpage,

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/CHANGELOG

Comment: Thank you for the CHANGRLOG information. But I cannot find any description about docker version in them. I will ask kubernetes team to upgrade the documents.

Comment: On the changelog for version 1.16, 
in the unchange section, there is this information I found, might be because there is no changes yet, from the website,                                                                     The list of validated docker versions remains unchanged,
The current list is 1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09, 18.06, 18.09. (#72823, #72831) https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.16.md#unchanged

Comment: I have confirmed the information on the changelog for version 1.16.
On  the changelog for version 1.17, 1.18 and 1.19, there is no change about the `Dependecies` section about docker version.
It seems that k8s 1.17, 1.18 and 1.19 support the same version. (1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09, 18.06, 18.09)